# August 2015 - Redirect loop - Can't log in to any Stack Exchange site with Opera Latest

Tags: support, login, stack-exchange-openid

I've searched many questions but none have helped so far.

I'm posting this question with Opera 12.17 because it works. I'm starting to use Opera Latest (currently 31) because many of the features that were lost when changing the engine to Chromium have been re-implemented.

However, trying to log into any Stack Exchange site with Opera Latest gives the following error:

> This webpage has a redirect loop
>
> The webpage at **[address]** has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

[image: This webpage has a redirect loop]

It works fine in Firefox Latest but I don't have Chrome installed to try it. Is this a site issue or a browser issue?